# loading secondary resources like images and such

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show image and its text initially as we open the page for my Image Slider.

This is my demo: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/15

here i am showing as all the DOM elements is loaded, but the need is to show the first image and its text initially for my slider as we open the page.

So I am not understanding how to load my initial image for my slider, so that its functionality starts after all DOM elements load.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term is "bootstrapping". You want the first image to load in as the DOM is loading, and before your script sets up the image slider.

One way to achieve this is to actually put the image in as part of the DOM. So, instead of an empty `src` in your image tag, put an actual url. Same for title and description.

I assume you're going to be doing an ajax request for the XML you're building in your example. If that's the case, then you probably have no way of knowing what the first image is, which means you'll still need a script to load data.

The performance gains from having two scripts will probably be negligible, but if you take that approach, make sure you load the smaller script in the `head` section of your html, and the longer one at the end of your `body`.